# sendSignedTransaction in web3.js takes too long

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js

This is the code I provided for sending a simple transaction to USDT contract on goerli network to mint some tokens. But when I run it takes too long until exceeds the limited timeout(which is not short by the way).

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;
const {HttpProvider, Web3, Contract} = require("web3")
const privateKey = "<PK>"
Buffer.from(privateKey , 'hex');

const w3 = new Web3('<endPoint>')
let USDT_ABI = '<abi>'
const USDTAddress = '0x5BCc22abEC37337630C0E0dd41D64fd86CaeE951'
let contract = new w3.eth.Contract(USDT_ABI, USDTAddress)
let owner = "<account address>"

let rawTransaction = {
    nonce: w3.utils.toHex(w3.eth.getTransactionCount(owner)),
    gasPrice: w3.utils.toHex(15),
    gasLimit: w3.utils.toHex(51302),
    from: owner,
    to: USDTAddress,
    data: contract.methods.mint('0x4b7fceBd9a645fAad26893f360Fe5b8b36B613e1', 10070000000).encodeABI()
}
w3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, privateKey).then(signature=>{
    console.log(signature.transactionHash);
    w3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signature.rawTransaction).then(console.log)
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is getting time out is maybe related to setting the inappropriate gas price and gas limit manually. You can try setting the higher gas limit or setting the current gas price of the network.

You can check the current gas prices on the network and adjust your values accordingly.

```
const gasPrice = await w3.eth.getGasPrice(); // Use current gas price from the network
```

You can also try increasing your gas limit.

```
gasLimit: w3.utils.toHex(60000), // Adjust based on the complexity of your transaction
```

Additionally,You can try running the code on a different network to ensure it's not a network specific issue.